# Does my code follow good clean code conventions?

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, revealing-module-pattern

Here is a class that I have implemented in order to sort rows of parameters in the form of an array of strings.

```
public class ParameterLinesSorter : IParameterLinesSorter
{
    private int identiferIndex;
    private IEnumerable<string[]> parameterLines;

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string[]>> Sort(IEnumerable<string[]> parameterLines, int identiferIndex)
    {
        this.identiferIndex = identiferIndex;
        this.parameterLines = parameterLines;

        return IsNotNullAndNotEmpty() ? FilterAndSort() : new List<IEnumerable<string[]>>();
    }

    private bool IsNotNullAndNotEmpty()
    {
        return parameterLines != null && parameterLines.Any();
    }

    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string[]>> FilterAndSort()
    {
        return parameterLines
            .Where(parameterLine => parameterLine.Any())
            .GroupBy(parameterLine => parameterLine.ElementAt(identiferIndex));
    }
}
```

Here is an example of use by a simple test :

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturnListWithTwoGroupsOfOneElement()
    {
        IEnumerable<string[]> parameterLines = new List<string[]>() {
            new string[]{ "C", "3", "3" },
            new string[]{ "M", "3", "5" }
        };


        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string[]>> expectedGroups = new List<IEnumerable<string[]>>() {
            new List<string[]>(){ new string[]{ "C", "3", "3" }},
            new List<string[]>(){ new string[]{ "M", "3", "5" }}
        };

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedGroups, sorter.Sort(parameterLines, 0));
    }
```

Note that this class and the Sort method will be used only once in all of the system.

Just before, the IsNotNullAndNotEmpty and FilterAndSort methods had arguments but I read that the best for a method was to have no arguments. Therefore, I preferred to pass identifierIndex and parameterLines as instance variables. Is it really a good practice ?

I am listening for any other recommendation.

Comment: Could you explain what this has to do with Javascript? I don't understand

Comment: Didn't sucseed to understand what the code is doing

Comment: Your title is too generic. Your title should describe what your code does.

Comment: "the best for a method was to have no arguments" is utter nonsense.

Comment: Thanks BCdotWEB for your first advice but i don't see how i can make the title less generic. "the best for a method was to have no arguments" comes from Clean Code book of Robert C Martin so i don't get this from anywhere but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important part of Clean Code is that your code should be easily understood. The author's indication about the number of parameters of a function is meant to be something like: "Better no parameters than one parameter. Better one parameter than two. You should avoid more than two parameters whenever it's possible"

For the function that checks the input `bool IsNotNullAndNotEmpty()` it would be more readable if you give it a parameter. It would read as: "is this thing null or empty". If you don't give it any parameter, maybe the name should be *ValidParameterLines*

There are more important guidelines in that book. For example, your code does more things than sort in that function, doesn't it?

- It filters the input excluding the empty
- It groups the input by the element at the indicated position

I don't really see the sorting part if I tell you the truth. I think that the function does something like classifying the parameters grouping them by a positional value.

What I'm trying to say is that the name of the function is misleading. That's a more important part of the Clean Code. You must write code that can be understood at first glance.

I hope that helps you

Comment: Thank you for your advice, By reading my code, i was thinking about the same thing so you confirm what i thought and it's what i expected ! The fact is that I'm French and I force myself to code in English so sometimes it's a bit difficult to find right names.

Comment: @MigMax most of the world is not natuve english speaker. But we all program in english. You don't want me to write code in hebrew and although i speak a little french i wouldn't like you to write code in it. Continue to work this way